# OWD Profiles and role hierarchy

Tags: owd

Thanks Prakash. I have another related question please

The OWD setting on a object ABC is set to Public REad Only and the Profile level access to my Manager on object ABC is set to Read .
Grant Access Using Hierarchies is set to Yes

So what access will my Manager have on my records ..Is it REad Only ( as per his Profile access) or REad and Write ...

Thankful for the clarity

Answer (score 0):

Profile permission comes first when user sees a record. So, ReadOnly on the object means he will see the record as view purpose.

If OWD settings of ABC  is Private then he can only view the record where he is the owner or he can see the subordinate's record based on the 'Grant Access Using Hierarchies is set to Yes'.

If OWD settings of ABC is Public Read Only, then not only he can view subordinate's record. he can see any records of ABC which has been created by others. Here 'Grant Access Using Hierarchies is set to Yes' doesn't add any extra visibility.

By the way, OWD settings governs the record level access which is the minimum access to the record provided user can at-least same kind of access at this profile.

Comment: Thank you very much this answers all my queries on this point.

Comment: If my answers serves your purpose then choose this so that others may find this useful.